# Is there any advantage to default export compared to named export?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, reactjs, typescript

I could list a ton of cases where named exports are absolutely beneficial. But `export default` is there and I see people using it quite often. Could somebody say examples to where it's preferable to named exports?

Comment: Export default is a historical problem, you don't really need to use it, and it's not preferred as well

Comment: Using default exports can encourage the script-writer to write modules that do / export only one thing, which is arguably useful for maintainability. (but, on the other hand, when you have no choice but to export something that does more than one thing, the syntax gets a bit ugly)

Comment: Thank you! Well, kind of yes. Those answers mostly mention what you can do with it, the only "benefit" seems to be that the developers can decide how to name the module, but it would be possible with normal export too. import { foo as bar } from './foo' It would be nice to see someone's opinion, who mostly uses default export.